# how resolve that: the constructor being called isnt' a const constructor. Try to remove 'const' from the invocation

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Something {
  Something({required this.first, required this.second});
  final String first;
  final String second;
}

class MapGood extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapGood({Key? key})
      : location = **const** Something(  // the constructor being called isnt' a const constructor. Try to remove 'const' from the invocation.
          first: "37.422",
          second: "-12",
        ),
        super(key: key);

  final Something? location;

  @override
  State<MapGood> createState() => _MapGoodState();
}

class _MapGoodState extends State<MapGood> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

In const constructor about class Something() in StatefulWidget MapGood is in error, if remove 'const' go in error for obvious reason.
Need to create a Stateful like that, where that input can be null, for that reason provide a default values.
I cannot understand how write this condition! i tried all passibility that i know but, every time dart pad (or vsCode) give me some errors.
That solution was give me by Codeium (or AI) and there is this error.

Comment: Just add `const` before `Something({required this.first, required this.second});`

Answer (score 3):

There are too many solutions

First one :

```
class Something {
  Something({required this.first, required this.second});
  final String first;
  final String second;
}

final class MapGood extends StatefulWidget {
   // Remove const 
   MapGood({super.key})
      : location = Something(
          first: '37.422',
          second: '-12',
        );

  final Something? location;

  @override
  State<MapGood> createState() => _MapGoodState();
}

class _MapGoodState extends State<MapGood> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

Other :

```
class Something {
  const Something({this.first = '37.422', this.second = '-12'});
  final String first;
  final String second;
}

final class MapGood extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapGood({super.key, this.location = const Something()});

  final Something? location;

  @override
  State<MapGood> createState() => _MapGoodState();
}

class _MapGoodState extends State<MapGood> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Either add `const` to the `Something` constructor, like

```
const Something({required this.first, required this.second});
```

or remove const from both in front of `Something` and `MapGood` like

```
class MapGood extends StatefulWidget {
  MapGood({Key? key})
      : location =  Something( 
  first: "37.422",
  second: "-12",
  ),
```